# php copy file with its path

Tags: php, file, copy

in php:
how to copy a file existng in 1/2/3 directory
to folder 0 ,  but if the nested folders 1/2/3 are not exist in 0,
it should create that folders (1 and 2 and 3), then copy the file into.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `mkdir` with the recursive flag before runing the copy

```
mkdir("/path/to/my/dir", 0700,true);
```